Allow duplicates in Power Automate sequential approval flow
I've created a SharePoint list, where each item needs approval by multiple people.  The first stage of the flow requires approval by an HRBP (HR Business Partner) and a Group Executive.
I'm using the Sequential Approval option in PA Solutions.  My whole flow works absolutely fine when the user specifies two different people in the HRBP and Group Executive fields, but if those  fields contain the same name (ie the same person is in both roles), then the flow fails with the following error:
Action 'Start_and_wait_for_an_approval_-_HRBP,_Group_Executive' failed: The request failed.
Error code: 'DuplicateApproverInSteps'. 
Error Message: 'Sequential approvals contains duplicate approvers.'.

Start of flow with error
I understand that logically, why would the same person need to approve twice, and usually this would probably hardly ever happen, but there will be cases where my end users will legitimately put the same name in both of these fields.
I understand I could use conditions to "daisy chain" the process based on something like "if HRBP rejects then mark as rejected, otherwise continue to next step" and then add a new approval step for the group exec.  But I have further conditions further into the flow, and I'm trying to minimise the "nested loops" so I'm keen to know if there is a way to allow duplicate approvers in the actual sequential approval flow function?
